# Google AdMob advertisement in iOS app shows only Image Ads and not Text Ads

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, admob

Over a week ago I set up a Google AdMob account and implemented banner advertisements using the platform SDK for iOS on iPhone.

In the AdMob account Ad Unit settings, I have precisely selected the **"Text" Ad** type (and unselected the "Image" Ad type). I only want to display "Text" Ads.

When the app is running, I would expect the banner should display text only advertisements and not image advertisements. However, that's not the case. When the app runs, the banner is only showing "Image" Ads and not "Text" Ads. The banner advertisements should be exclusively showing only text ads.

---

**Swift code**

```
var bannerView: GADBannerView!
bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
bannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50)
bannerViewBackground.addSubview(bannerView)
bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-1234567890123456789/1234567890" // Example ID
```

---

> **Question**
>
> Why is AdMob showing "Image" Ads when it should instead only be
>   showing "Text" Ads?
>
> What's going on here and how can I correct it?

---

**Images**

*AdMob Ad Unit settings*

[image]

*Text Ads style*

[image]

*Image Ads style*

[image]